# Automated OTT and Mobile Network Traffic Capture

Tags: networking, automation, appium, browserstack, ott

I am trying to devise a solution through which we can capture network traffic (HAR export HTTPS requests) in an automated fashion across different devices - whether they be mobile or different OTT platforms.

Ideally, without having to maintain my own device farm, though I'm still open to solutions that involve hosting a device farm.

I am aware of utilizing something like BrowserStack in order to test devices remotely, and capture the network traffic from those devices using their native network traffic capture feature.

However, it appears that they currently do not offer all platforms (mobile + fireTV & tvOS), with the latter two having quite a high cost.

Wondering if anyone else is leveraging any other similar solutions, or if there are any other solutions that are recommended for traffic monitoring on OTT platforms